Webscrape a link from a button with python
I am trying to webscrape a link that belongs to a previous button on this website. (The final purpose is to enrich data for a RAG chatbot)
https://onlinehelp.prinect-lounge.com/Prinect_Color_Toolbox/Version2021/de_10/#t=Prinect%2Fmeasuring%2Fmeasuring-4.htm

The prev/next buttons are in the top right corner. The link that has to be extracted on the given example subpage would be this one:
href="https://onlinehelp.prinect-lounge.com/Prinect_Color_Toolbox/Version2021/de_10/Prinect/measuring/measuring-3.htm"

I tried the standard way with Beautifulsoup:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://onlinehelp.prinect-lounge.com/Prinect_Color_Toolbox/Version2021/de_10/#t=Prinect%2Fmeasuring%2Fmeasuring-4.htm"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# get full html section
test1 = soup.find(id="browseSeqBack")
print(test1)

# get full html section test 2
test2 = soup.find("div", class_="brs_previous").children
print(test2)

# get link directly test 3
secBackButton = soup.find(id="browseSeqBack")
href = secBackButton.attrs.get('href', None)
print(href)


However, neither do test 1 and 2 deliver the whole html section, nor does the direct query for the link work.
this section comes back with test1:
<a class="wBSBackButton" data-attr="href:.l.brsBack" data-css="visibility: @.l.brsBack?'visible':'hidden'" data-rhwidget="Basic" id="browseSeqBack">
                                                 <span aria-hidden="true" class="rh-hide" data-html="@KEY_LNG.Prev"></span>

Thanks in Advance :)

Check the page source that the server is returning.  The section being returned for "test1" is exactly what's in the page source.  It sounds like this page may have some client-side code which modifies the DOM, and you want the modified DOM.  BeautifulSoup alone doesn't support this.  You likely want to use a "headless browser" tool (e.g. Selenium) which doesn't only download the initial page source but internally includes a browser engine to execute JavaScript, etc.  The resulting DOM would then have what you're looking for.

The actual content is within an iframe that has a slightly different url; Prinect/measuring/measuring-4.htm instead of #t=Prinect%2Fmeasuring%2Fmeasuring-4.htm
You can get the content + the next & previous paths like this:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base_url = 'https://onlinehelp.prinect-lounge.com/Prinect_Color_Toolbox/Version2021/de_10/'
path = 'Prinect/measuring/measuring-4.htm' 

response = requests.get(urljoin(base_url, path))
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

prev_path = soup.head.select_one('meta[name=brsprev]').get('value')
next_path = soup.head.select_one('meta[name=brsnext]').get('value')

print(f'previous: {urljoin(base_url, prev_path)}')
print(f'next: {urljoin(base_url, next_path)}')


Works perfectly well, even anticipating that I need the next button as well ;)  Thanks a ton!

@Jefferson no problem!

This is lazyload, so it doesn't load immediately. I tried using selenium, and adding solid wait, and it worked.
